# DEM Rendered Terrain looks stairstepped/pixilated/pitted

Tags: rendering, height-map

I am making a map in Blender from a 30m DEM. When I render it, some places come out stair-stepped or pitted. [image: First screenshot of hill area][image: Second Screenshot of desert area]

Comment: What is the bit-depth of the DEM you are using? Too low could cause stepping or banding.

Comment: I have tried to play with it some. The data in this screenshot was a Float32.